# Azure vmss without a load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

My requirement is to scale vm instance (linux based custom image) based on CPU usage. Tried to follow steps mentioned in VMSS (virtual machine scale sets : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-linux-autoscale), but it creates a LB in front which we don't want. Is it possible to avoid LB in vmss ?

If VMSS without LB is not the option, is there any other way in azure to do this ? 
I am able to achieve this in AWS (using autoscale group) and GCP (instance group), so trying to get similar functionality in Azure.

hp

Comment: Do you mean you don't want LB with a public IP?

Comment: I don't want LB at all. but want public IP for all instances in set.

Comment: if you don't want to add LB, we can use classic module, create VMs in cloud service, and setting scale, azure will create a built-in LB for those VMs.

Answer (score 2):

In powershell to make this work you need to provide both double quotes wrapped in single quotes:  `--load-balancer '""'`

```
az vmss -n myName -g myGroup --load-balancer '""' --image UbuntuLTS
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass empty id as a load-balancer

```
az vmss create -n myname -g mygroup --load-balancer "" --public-ip-per-vm --image UbuntuLTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Though a load balancer is created when you create a VM scale set in the portal, other modes supporting external connectivity to scale sets include:

- Create a separate VM with a public IP address in the same VNET as the scale set which can route connections to the scale set VMs (also known as a jump box). E.g. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-windows-jumpbox or https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-linux-jumpbox
- Assign a public IP address to each VM in the scale set. This feature is currently in limited preview. See here for more details: https://github.com/gbowerman/azure-myriad/tree/master/publicip-dns

Answer (score 0):

Public IP per VM in a scale set is not supported today but is on the roadmap. If you submit a support request (e.g. from the question mark in the top-right of the azure portal), we can keep you informed on the timeline :).

Comment: This is now available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#public-ipv4-per-virtual-machine